# Finding absolute points in a closed area

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

$f(x,y)$ is $x^2+xy+y^2$. I need the max and min points for $f(x,y)$ in and on the rectangle $-2≤x≤2$ and $-1≤y≤1$.

What I did was;

$$f_x'=2x+y+y^2 = 0$$

$$f_y'=x^2+x+2y = 0$$

I couldn't implement the restriction of the rectangle.

Comment: How to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your partial derivatives are wrong. You should treat the variable you are not differentiating as a constant, so you have:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x} = 2x + y$$
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta y} = x+2y$$

From this information, you can find the minimum value. Since the maximum value would be unbounded if there was no restriction, the maximum value must occur on the vertices of the region.

Comment: So the answer is (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, and for the maximum just evaluate the function at the vertices.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I use the restrictions of the rectangle in the f function to find the max point?

Comment: Yes, substitute $(-2,-1), (-2, 1), (2, -1)$ and $(2,1)$ into the function and the largest value out of these four points is the maximum. This comes from the theory of [linear programming](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-programming/).